# I'm trying to execute vue code after call controller method in .net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a problem in my .net project, I'm trying to insert a js variable declared in vue, this is to be able to save form data temporarily, but inside the view where I call the file that contains the vue code I have a partial view, so if I try to do something like this:

```
@{
var urlAdd = Url.RouteUrl("EATAddMainExpertOpinion", new { id = ViewBag.CDIId });
var urlAdd2 = Url.RouteUrl("EATExpertOpinionAddRequestMP", new { id = ViewBag.CDIId });
var urlEdit = Url.RouteUrl("EATCompleteExpertOpinion", new { id = ViewBag.CDIId });
bool haveCDI = false;
}
<div id="expertopinion-app" class="mb-2">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card class="card-without-style">
        <v-card-title class="card-without-style-title">
            Dictamenes Periciales
        </v-card-title>
        <br />
        <hr />
    </v-card>
    <v-row class="px-4 mb-2" justify="space-between">
        <v-col cols="4">
            <v-sheet>
                <v-text-field v-model="search"
                              label="Filtrar..."
                              flat
                              clearable
                              clear-icon="fas fa-times"></v-text-field>
            </v-sheet>
            <v-treeview :items="items"
                        :active.sync="active"
                        :open.sync="open"
                        :filter="filter"
                        :search="search"
                        open-all
                        item-text="title"
                        expand-icon="fas fa-caret-down"
                        activatable
                        hoverable
                        rounded dense
                        transition>
            </v-treeview>
        </v-col>
        <v-divider vertical></v-divider>
        <v-col class="d-flex text-center">
            <v-scroll-y-transition mode="out-in">
                @if (!haveCDI)
                {
                    <a @@click="hola"
                       class="btn btn-primary text-white">
                        <i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-fw"></i>Agregar dictamen a perito
                    </a>
                    <div v-if="!selected" class="mx-auto" style="align-self: center;" flat max-width="400">
                        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-action"
                           href="@urlAdd" class="btn btn-primary text-white">
                            <i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-fw"></i>Agregar dictamen
                        </a>
                        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-action"
                           href="@urlAdd2" class="btn btn-primary text-white">
                            <i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-fw"></i>Agregar dictamen a perito
                        </a>
                    </div>
                }
             </v-scroll-y-transition>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
 </v-app>
</div>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to run vue code inside my view, my vue code is inside a div where its id="expertopinion-app", when calling my js function it executes, but when calling the UrlAdd2 controller method, A partial view is called, and inside it I try to execute the vue code, but any function that I try to execute inside, all it does is execute the "Details" method inside the controller, which is the one that opens the view where there is my div="expertopinion-app", here is my vue code and controller:

```
    var data =@Json.Serialize(Model.ExpertOpinionSummaries);
    var readOnly =@isReadOnly.ToString().ToLower();
    var expertopinion = new Vue({
        vuetify: new Vuetify(),
        el: '#expertopinion-app',
        data: () => ({
            readOnly: readOnly,
            active: [],
            open: [],
            expertopinion: data,
            search: null,
            caseSensitive: false,
            dialog: false,
            OffOpinions: new OffOpinions(),
            opinionTemp: new ExpOpinions(0, '', '', '', '', ''),

        }),
        computed: {
            filter() {
                return this.caseSensitive
                    ? (item, search, textkey) => item[textkey].indexOf(search) > -1
                    :undefined
            },
            items() {
                return [{
                    title: 'Dictamenes Periciales',
                    children: this.expertopinion
                }]
            },
            selected() {
                if (!this.active.length)
                    return undefined;
                const id = this.active[0];
                var node = this.findNode(id, this.items[0]);
                if (typeof node.id == 'undefined') return undefined;
                return node;
            },
            isReadOnly() {
                return this.readOnly;
            }
        },
        methods: {
            findNode(id, currentNode) {
                let i,
                    currentChild,
                    result;
                if (id == currentNode.id) {
                    return currentNode;
                } else {
                    if (typeof currentNode.children != 'undefined') {
                        for (i = 0; i < currentNode.children.length; i += 1) {
                            currentChild = currentNode.children[i];
                            result = this.findNode(id, currentChild);
                            if (result!==false) {
                                return result;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            },
            loader(typeF) {
                var id = this.selected.id;
                viewReportCompletePDFFile(id,typeF);
            },
            hola() {
                console.log("hola");
            },
            addOpinion() {
                let form = $("#formexp");
                form.validate();
                if (form.valid()) {
                    this.opinionTemp.id++;
                    this.OffOpinions.expops.push(this.opinionTemp.makeCopy());
                    this.hideModal("modal-action-opinion");
                    this.clearOpinion();
                }
            },
            clearOpinion() {
                this.opinionTemp.cdid = '';
                this.opinionTemp.numbero = '';
                this.opinionTemp.dateo = '';
                this.opinionTemp.recepdate = '';
                this.opinionTemp.docof = '';
            }
        }
    })
```

Controlador:

> 

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Details/ExpertOpinion/{id}/AddRequestMP",Name="EATExpertOpinionAddRequestMP")]
    public IActionResult AddExpertOpinionRequestMP(Guid Id)
    {
        return PartialView("../Partials/CDI/ExpertOpinion/_AddRequestMP",new CreateExpertOpinionRequestMP { CDIId=Id});
    }
```

My question is, because my vue code runs fine in my view, but when I call the GET method of the controller and get the new view, my vue code is no longer responsive, how can I make it responsive?